# About up-votes.

Tags: discussion, voting, statistics, up-votes

Recently, meta has seen an uprising of questions related to downvotes/toxicity of the community etc. There are posts mentioning behaviour towards younger users, random downvotes etc.

But I have seen none (if there is, please correct me) talking about another index of this toxicity: the low amount of upvotes on questions.

I've been using MSE for quite a considerable time. I sincerely didn't see much change on the downvote behaviour, and downvotes are given a big highlight in discussion. However, upvoting seems to have decreased *a lot* in the recent times. I've been making this experience in the recent weeks: I go to the front page and scroll down all questions. Sometimes, $80\%$ of the questions are not voted at all. Some questions have $3$ answers and are not voted. I think this may be an interesting phenomenon to consider.

Therefore, I have two objectives with this post:

1. Could someone come up with the statistics that would prove/disprove my assertion that upvotes have considerably diminished?
2. If that is the case, why do you think this is happening?

And one of the points I wish to make is: whenever people seem to complain about the behaviour, they touch the downvotes. They may touch the upvotes-issue, but the focus is always on downvotes. However, I think that low spread of upvotes has its consequences. To ask a question and not receive attention makes people less inclining to ask. They will ask only if they have a "perfect" question in some sense. Meanwhile, people not acquainted to the site will ask away anyway, since they do not care. And then we end up having more chance of a flood of bad questions, since we do not encourage enough the good ones

---

OBS: The title of the question is intended to be dual to [this one](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21157/about-downvotes), which was poorly received.

Comment: Please do not pad titles with MathJax. There are specific tags on meta; please use them.

Comment: Over a year up-votes decreased by about 10% at about constant number of new questions.

Comment: @quid Sorry, will remember next time. Hmm... that seems (intuitively) a low number. Is that a high value, in terms of sheer quantity? Or even relatively speaking, comparing to other years?

Comment: Actually having looked close the number of questions is also a bit lower. The total number (vote decrease) is about 2k per week. It doesn't account for Q&A split though. It's the global number of votes. I'll see if I can find better data.

Comment: The numbers of up- and down-votes can be checked in [site analytics](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/21347) and several users have created queries for some other stats, see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6668/) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11992/up-and-downvote-statistics). If you search a bit, you will probably find a few more similar posts. For example, you might have a look at questions tagged [statistics+voting](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/statistics+voting) and similar reasonable combinations of tags.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Is there any statistic concerning the "spread" of upvotes?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by *spread*. But probably a natural thing to do would be to look at other posts about voting stats (there is at least 10 posts here on meta concerned with various stats about upvotes and downvotes, see my previous comment) to see whether some of them contains the information you are interested in.

Comment: By spread I mean the fact that a question may have 40 upvotes while 20 other questions may have 0. I saw your links, and only [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/22010/is-voting-on-questions-getting-harsher), [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11992/up-and-downvote-statistics), [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16724/why-is-there-a-decreases-in-number-of-upvotes-and-increase-in-downvotes) and [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6668/statistics-on-upvoting) questions touch the issue I mention, with only the latter directly so.

Comment: Furthermore, all those links seem outdated.

Comment: One of the points I wish to make is: whenever people seem to complain about the behaviour, they touch the downvotes. They may touch the upvotes-issue, but the focus is always on downvotes. However, I think that low spread of upvotes has its consequences. To ask a question and not receive attention makes people less inclining to ask. They will ask only if they have a "perfect" question in some sense. Meanwhile, people not acquainted to the site will ask away anyway, since they do not care. And then we have the flood of bad questions we do, since we do not encourage enough the good ones.

Comment: Re: *Outdated links.* Several of the questions you mention describe the stats at the time of the post, but the SEDE query which was used the get the stats is also linked there. So you can get more recent stats simply by running those queries with the parameters of your choice. (Although you will not see upvotes and downvotes on the [site analytics page](http://math.stackexchange.com/site-analytics), since it is shown only to 25K+ users.)

Comment: Re: *Spread*. [This answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/22012) contains [a query calculating average score](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/395828#graph) (for posts posted on the same day). It seems that you want something similar with median instead of average. I do not know SQL well-enough to know how difficult is to modify it like that.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Yes, I mean median. Thank you. I've used some of the queries, but they all seem to point to average. And to be honest, I don't know how to correctly interpret the data. PS: This last query you linked show a heavy downwards spike on September. Is that anything special, or am I missing something?

Comment: I guess that the different behavior in the past month might be caused by the fact, that many older heavily downvoted posts get deleted and do not appear in the stats. (A minor factor might also be that recent posts had shorter time to gain upvotes.) This was also discussed [in the previous post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/22010/is-voting-on-questions-getting-harsher/22012#comment85913_22012). BTW if you wish to clean-up these comments a bit, feel free to ping me [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/19138/2016/9/25).

Comment: I've noticed that many questions don't receive upvotes I think they deserve too. I try to upvote questions often and would love to have this emphasized.

Comment: Also, from days of yore, http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/662/vote-early-vote-often

Comment: Relevant is http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1942237. Does it really deserve 200+ upvotes for its content, which is **not even completely correct** (mismatching units)? You know the reason it has gotten so many upvotes, which is a significant flaw in the SE reputation model, but there is nothing SE wants to do about it.

Comment: Another thing I noticed is the  lack of "Accepted" for an answer. Even if there are 4 or more good answers, many times the OP does not Accept. Why not? The answers you get are free, the least one can do is a "thank you" by accepting.

Comment: @imranfat: Some newcomers are genuinely not aware of the possibility of accepting answers. Sometimes an answer that might seem good to many of us with more experience just isn’t helpful to the beginner who asked the question. And of course some are simply thoughtless. (And sometimes they come back several *years* later and accept an answer: I’ve had that happen several times in the last few months.)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Ok, that makes sense.

Comment: Relavant is also [this post from our now dusty blog](http://math.blogoverflow.com/2015/05/10/growth-statistics-on-math-se/). For what it's worth, I would think that some of this is due to the growth of the site --- questions spend less time on the front page, and so have less time to be noticed and upvoted. However it is true that there are fewer upvotes than a year ago (yet much more than 2 years ago), so this explanation is at least incomplete, if not totally incorrect.

Comment: I can personally attest to the "only ask a perfect question" result of no upvotes. I'm living that right now.

Comment: I found your meta question here, I can't help to ask you this question: If you encourage upvoting, how come you only have 1727 upvotes in 66 months? This is less that 1 upvote per day. Please come up with a reasonable explanation.

Comment: @scaaahu The reasonable explanation is that you are probably correct, I don't vote as much as I should (this is sort of implicit in my questionnaire's answer when I mention "users (and I include myself in this) tend to, over time, diminish their upvoting pattern"). Nonetheless, there are some points I'd like to touch: First, I've changed my mind slightly about the issue. Here, I was intending to have more upvotes *in general* (which is implicit when I talk about the "spread" of votes). Now, I am more surgical about it: "vote up more often in content **that you think is desirable**".

Comment: Second, in order to improve my votes, I've made some rules of thumb for myself, one of them being that if I answer some question, it is because I think it is desirable content, so it only makes sense that I upvote it. So, while I effectively don't vote very often, some thought and action has gone into the issue into how to improve without ending out voting for content that may be undesirable.

Comment: Lastly, although I agree with your remark that I don't upvote often, I am not sure if your statistics are fair. People have different activities, different criteria etc, and taking (Upvotes/Number of days you have been a member on the site) seems very reductionist. Not to mention that in 2013 I had less than 20 Q+A, and in 2014 I had around the same number.

Comment: _People have different activities_ How come you have conducted only [281 reviews](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/59234/aloizio-macedo?tab=activity&sort=reviews)? Math SE is not my primary site. Academia SE is. Please look at my [review stats on Academia SE](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/546/scaaahu?tab=activity&sort=reviews). Also, you only have 39 helpful flags on Math SE, even less than mine on Math SE. I have over 1500 helpful flags on my primary site Academia.

Comment: @scaaahu You can read underlying reasons for that in my response to amWhy under [my nomination](https://math.stackexchange.com/election/7?tab=nomination). If you find any of that unsatisfactory, I respect that.

Comment: Do you understand that you don't have too much chance to do reviews if you're elected? This is because moderators have decisive powers, once they take action when doing review, the review is over. No one else has chance to express different views. My advice for you: before you're elected, do review as much as possible. Raise flags when appropriate. Be a normal user first.

Comment: @scaaahu Yes, I do understand, which is precisely why I think that being measured is not necessarily a bad thing, but a thing to reach balance. One could argue, conversely, that someone who engages in doing review "as much as possible" would not be a good moderator, since they would have to be much more restrained about their actions later. The point is: both are points with some truth to it, but there are several more variables than simple numbers beneath it. As I implied, if you find that I would be an unsatisfactory moderator, I respect that. I don't think there is much more to discuss.

Answer (score 19):

I fully agree we should vote (both up and down) far more.

On the topic of upvoting questions...hey, it's free! And very few people will complain! So upvote away!

I have a suggestion/recommendation I want to throw out there and as always upvote/downvote me for agree/disagree.

**If you see a question that is above your level, even if you do not understand it, if it looks stylistically well written, I recommend you upvote it.**

There are so many fantastic questions that are on advanced topics that receive little attention. I always upvote questions I might not understand, but look well written.

By upvoting you are not saying that "this is correct", you are just saying "this is roughly the type of question we should be encouraging".

The worst case scenario is that you upvote a question that is bad for subtle reasons. However you can reward and encourage not obviously bad questions. I think it's a pretty fair trade off.

Comment: Agreed, i upvote based on quality and presentation for the reason of encouraging more, i downvote for the opposite reason.

Comment: In this answer 2 objectives of OP has not been answer.

Comment: "it looks stylistically well written, I recommend you upvote it" $\implies +1$